# Using laravels {{old}} on dynamically created inputs

Tags: laravel, input, persistent

I have a form which allows a user to create an unlimited number of fields. If this forms fails validation I want the user to return to this page with the form populated with their previous input values - i.e. I want these fields to persist.

With a normal form I could do this with {{ old 'title' }}, however, these additional fields are being generated through JavaScript and so I cannot add this PHP snippet. What is the best way for me to retrieve these previous input values?

Comment: use the name of those other fields, that's how it is. like, `old('generated_field_1')`

Comment: if the form validation fails then the appended fields are gone, use front-end validation instead of back-end validation for such fields

Answer (score 2, accepted):

3 ways to do this, cache, sessions and cookies.

[cache](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/cache) and [sessions](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/session#using-the-session) are server side which is much better for security, however it will take extra time and effort for setting up, but if the data is not sensible and can be passed within cookies, better to the [cookies](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp).

The best thing about cookies for your current situation is: you can set it up directly from your front end JS code.